# Eigenvalue markov chain

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a questions: We said that if we have a positive recurrent Markov chain, then there is a unique stationary distribution.

1.) Does this mean that if I have several positive recurrent classes, then each one corresponds to a separate stationary distribution? ( This is what my intuition tells me)

2.) Furthermore: If we have two disjoint sets $A \cap B = \emptyset$, $q(x) = \mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A > \tau_B)$ then we have  $q|_A(x)=0$, $q|_B(x)=1$ and $(Id-P)q(x)=0$, where $P$ is the transition matrix. ($\tau$ is the recurrence time)

Now I was wondering: Does the converse also hold, so if we have a $q$ that satisfies $q|_A(x)=0$, $q|_B(x)=1$ and $(Id-P)q(x)=0$, where $P$ is the transition matrix, can we infer from this that $q(x) = \mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A > \tau_B)$.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Again? "if we have a positive recurrent Markov chain, then there is a unique stationary distribution" is wrong without irreducibility.

Comment: @Did yes, it is me again. well, i meant that there is just this one positive recurrent class that encompasses the whole chain, so yes: irreducibility was meant to be implied.

Comment: Then why do you repeat this question about "several positive recurrent classes"?

Comment: well, our theorem says: If your whole chain is one pos.recurrent class, then you get a stationary distribution. So I think a reasonable question is: If your chain consists of $n-$ pos. recurrent classes, does this mean that you get $n$ stationary distributions? I think it is reasonable to assume that this is true cause you could restrict the domain of your chain to this particular class and you will end up with an eigenvalue, but I was just wondering whether anybody could confirm this. The more interesting question is probably the second one.

Comment: The second question is also explained in every textbook on the subject: the difference of the functions is harmonic on the complement of A and B and zero on A and B hence the maximum principle tells you it is zero everywhere, QED.

Comment: @Did thanks, and my reasoning about 1.) was correct?

Comment: Sorry but which part of "this is basic stuff which is explained in every textbook on the subject" do you fail to get?

Comment: @Did thanks, now I got it. How could I have missed this? That's the great think about Mathematics, you always get a straight answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re 2., note that the difference of the functions is harmonic on the complement of A and B and zero on A and B hence the maximum principle shows that it is zero everywhere, QED.